# gdb :add excecutable in runtime

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have started running the gdb with a executable say out1 i.e `gdb out1` . Now I realised that I missed to add few checks in the code and upon adding the code I generated the new exec file say out2. Now is it possible to add this `out2` to the already running `gdb out1` so that I can debug with the new added checks exec code. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You want to load out2 without quitting gdb. Am I correct?
I think you can run "file out2" in gdb, then gdb will kill out1 and load out2.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the name `out1`, kill the currenly running process (`(gdb) k`) and start it again (`(gdb) r`). The GDB will reload the new data/code/debug info.

Comment: Killing is done implicitly if one just commands `run` while the app is already running.